# Multiple wildcard certificates for same common name on different servers

Tags: ssl, certificate, wildcard

We've recently ventured into the cloud for hosting a number of websites.

On our on-premise hosting we're using a wildcard certificate for a number of websites, and we want to do the same for our cloud hosted websites ( especially since the PAAS loadbalancer can only host one certificate). We do not want to reuse the on-premise certificate in the cloud solution, in order to limit the environments which are impacted if a certificate would be compromised.

This would mean that there would be two wildcard certificates for the same CN (*.example.com).

I found some webpages about there being problems on iOS devices not supporting multiple certificates for the same CN and wondered if there are other technical limitations to this solution.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use two different certificate for the same common name.

We have tested many domains for the same query, and we've never found any problem on iOS devices, so 2 different domains for same domain name will work fine on iOS devices.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using different certificates with different hostnames there should be no problem, even if the certificates are wild card. If you instead use different certificates with the same hostname (i.e. different IP address and server, but same hostname) you might run into problems because this setup is valid but unusual and at least security extension like Certificate Patrol will probably complain.